# How to select student login from http request?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to log in my [college grading website](http://www.mitsims.in/home.jsp) but I could not select the student option through requests. This is python code:

```py
   import requests
   payload={"stuLogin":True,'userId':'someuserID',"password":"somePassword" }
   with requests.Session() as s:
       p = s.post('http://www.mitsims.in/home.jsp#', data=payload)     
       print(p.text)
       r = s.get('http://www.mitsims.in/studentIndex.html') 
       print(r.text)`
```

How to select student login from http request?

Answer (score 0):

If that dictionary on line 2 should be the *payload*, I think you should define the variable name:

```
payload = {"stuLogin":True,'userId':'userID',"password":"passWord" }
```

Comment: yeah but its not came .